# What is this white fluffy material?

Tags: materials

I've been finding this material all around my house for the last six months.  To give you some perspective, the sample below is about 2 inches by 1 inch.  The sizes of the pieces I find vary considerably in size from less than 1 inch to almost a square foot.  The larger pieces tend to be flat like a layer. Other houses in the neighborhood don't seem to have this so it seems to come from our house.

I live in a house that has been converted into two condos and the other unit had construction done last year.  Most was internal, but they did have a sky light put in.  I wonder if the construction left a hole somewhere that allows an animal to get in a retrieve this material.

Any idea what it is?  It feels synthetic.  Figuring out what it is should hopefully help us find the problem and fix it!

[image]

Comment: Is it carpet fiber? When I vaccuum my carpet, my bagless vac pulls up some of the fiber and the resulting bits look a lot like your photo.

Comment: @chuex, nope, there are some bigger pieces that are definitely not carpet fiber.

Comment: Voting to close. We're being asked to guess what some white stuff is through the internet with very little information.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you have a rodent problem, and I'd guess that you're finding bits of your furniture padding/batting that were in the way of a cozy nest. How else could something like this just appear "around the house"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like insulation, fiberglass or polyester perhaps. Usually used on top of ceilings or in stud wall cavities.

Does though also look a bit like hobby stuffing or cushion filling.

Could be a few things.

Comment: It isn't fiberglass, but does feel like polyester.  It does look and feel like cushion filling but I'm pretty sure there are no cushions lying around...